# UICollisionBehavior collide with background view only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidynamicbehavior, uicollisionbehavior

In my ViewController, I have a background view and a bunch of collision views. I have added gravity behavior to those collision views, so that they will fall from their original positions. But I want to let these views stop falling when they reach the bottom of the screen. So I add collision behavior to each collision view. Meanwhile I don't want them to collide with each other. In another word, each collision view can overlap with other collision views. I have tried

```
[_collision setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundaryWithInsets:NO]
```

But it does't work, and I guess I'm using the wrong method. So how can I achieve this?